# Varnish caching wordpress site per user or UA (i am not sure). I want the caching to be universal

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, varnish

I have recently switched a website from generic PHP to wordpress driven.  The varnish front-end is the same except for rules to accommodate  wp-admin.

I find the cache-hit is unique to my connection and the hit count  increases distinctly for me and a friend viewing the same site but  different machines.

I tried changing vcl_hash and reduced to simply

```
sub vcl_hash {
   set req.hash += req.url;
   set req.hash += req.http.host;
}
```

Still the cache served is unique to both of us. Meaning if I see hit  count of say '10' the the next hit by my friend should ideally be '11';   but he gets  '1' as hit count and it increments to '2' and so on if he  keeps refreshing the page

I hope some one can help me identify why this is happening. It seems to  be happening for other wordpress sites as well. It came to my notice due  to the transition from php-based to Wordpress driven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your backend server is Apache + Wordpress, and you are using mod_deflate, then check its Vary headers.

If Vary header shows 'user agent' or 'cookie' in it then Varnish will cache as per user agent. You can unset vary in Apache (edit: or in vcl_fetch in varnish, I haven't tried it though). 
I had success with use of setEnv in the virtual host configuration.

```
setEnv force-no-vary
```

But, I noticed this setting changes HTTP version to HTTP/1.0. However, I am not using feature such as Keep-Alive, so it didnt matter much. I think, eventually, remote client gets HTTP/1.1 with Varnish in between (correct me if I am wrong).

If you are setting cookies, then you may want to deal with it differently.

Answer (score 0):

Comment your hash function (if you don't need it), and try again. The hash is what is making the hits [unique to that request](https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/VCL_functions.html#vcl-vcl-hash).

Comment: I commented vcl_hash function and checked..but still not working.

Comment: And you restarted varnish as well?

Comment: yeah i restarted the same..but no luck...

Comment: Post your vcl. Also, compare the output of `varnishlog` for your hit and your friend's hit (Warning: If the site is use, there will be a lot of data, and you will have to do some scrubbing of the output).

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that varnish' default VCL is appended to your custom VCL if you don't perform a `return` action.

So in your case (I think you're using Varnish 2.x due to the syntax), you are probably not sanitizing request cookies and the default VCL is hashing them. (It'll be better to examine your full VCL config and the default.vcl aplied)

You can try a couple of things.

**Add a return action**

```
sub vcl_hash {
   set req.hash += req.url;
   set req.hash += req.http.host;
   return (hash);
}
```

**Conditional hashing**

```
sub vcl_hash {
   if ( ! req.url ~ "wp-admin") {
     set req.hash += req.url;
     set req.hash += req.http.host;
     return (hash);
   }
}
```

**Sanitizing cookies**

```
sub vcl_recv {
   # ...
   # Before reurning a lookup
   if ( ! req.url ~ "wp-admin") {
     unset req.http.Cookie;
   }
   # ...
}
```